# How to trace these crashes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have been working with Obj-C, Xcode from years, but at times these crash happens to a project. I have no clue how to deal with these.

If someone has any idea, please guide me towards right direction, so that I can workout.

NOTE: The following logs are sent by customer from the live app.

Snipped of crash log is;

```html
Date/Time:             2018-02-08 16:39:36.053 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        163431E3-7543-821C-B71C-392218AA5AD3

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1D59C34E-52D6-4F57-A2CE-4C8FAC4387FE

Time Awake Since Boot: 9100 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fffdb6ca521 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 9
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fffdb6c18fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
2   libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fffdb6ceaac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 925
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fffc5facbc9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fffc5f6dc0d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fffc5f6d114 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
6   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fffc54cdebc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
7   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fffc54cdcf1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
8   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x00007fffc54cdb26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
9   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fffc3a66a54 _DPSNextEvent + 1120
10  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fffc41e27ee -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796
11  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fffc3a5b3db -[NSApplication run] + 926
12  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fffc3a25e0e NSApplicationMain + 1237
13  libdyld.dylib                  0x00007fffdb6f7235 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fffdb825bf2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fffdb9117fa _pthread_cond_wait + 712
2   libc++.1.dylib                 0x00007fffda28e4cd std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 47
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore       0x00007fffc8f7b43c void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 108
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore       0x00007fffc8f7b3bb bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 155
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore       0x00007fffc8f7b28d bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*) + 29
6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore       0x00007fffc8f7b53d void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 93
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fffdb91093b _pthread_body + 180
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fffdb910887 _pthread_start + 286
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fffdb91008d thread_start + 13
```

Comment: It's not giving you much to go on.  Have you tried building/running with Address Sanitizer turned on?

Comment: This bug is sent by an end user of a app, that is live.

Comment: Even if you can't reproduce the crash, ASan might be a good way to check for memory problems that *could* cause a crash under some unknown conditions.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can fix it with that information. I would recommend adding a crash reporting library like Instabug, it sometimes helps you get more information by telling you what was in the console at the time of the crash.

Comment: Bugs like this are almost always over-release bugs. While rare in ARC applications, they can still happen (especially if you have unsafe pointers, foundation references, etc.) I find most of these in development by turning on Zombie objects or profile the app using the Allocations tool. If the customer is game, it's also possible to run your app in the field by enabling Zombies using an environment variable (see [OS X debugging magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2124/_index.html)).

Answer (score 2):

```
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffdb6ca521 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 9
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffdb6c18fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffdb6ceaac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 925
```

The crash is happening when GCD is trying to execute a block on the main thread.   Check you callback blocks to make sure they are cleanly capturing state and that all blocks that need to be copied are copied correctly.

This is *likely* because there is some object captured by the block that was prematurely released *or* because the block itself was over-released (unlikely).

Comment: Thanks, that too I understand. But how to know where it happened? I have more than 300 classes and there are many sync & async blocks working in the background.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Start setting up breakpoints in the debugger with a `.dSYM` file in Xcode... You know the crash happens on the main thread so that should narrow it down a bit.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I feel your pain.  But without more evidence, inspection is all your left with.  It is quite frustrating.